# AppCode - Debug C++ program within Objective-C project?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, jetbrains-ide, appcode

I have an Objective-C project with a large portion of it written in C++. I've also written a C++ main file in the project which allows the processing done in the C++ side of things to be run as a standalone without the iOS component. Is there anyway to setup a C++ debug execution configuration inside of the iOS project? As far as I can see I can only create configurations meant to run on an iOS device when in an iOS project. Yet, AppCode does have the project type to create command line tools. Is there anyway to enable those command line tool configurations inside of an iOS project? Thank you much!

Comment: Why don't you just add an OSX Command Line Tool target to your project? That should allow you to repurpose that project to run your C++ code.

Comment: @MobileBen: Can I do this without creating a separate project? If so, could you explain how? That work work great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can do it using your current project.

Here are some screenshots which hopefully are clear enough. Note this is Xcode 6.

In Xcode, in the Nav Area, select the project (selected on the left in the image). You'll see your targets. Click on that '+' to add a new target.

[image: Add Target]

You'll then get a a dialog sheet where you can select your OSX Command Line Tool. It will then let you configure how that target is setup.

[image: Create Target Dialog]

Comment: Perfect. In AppCode, it's just under project settings, but from there it's basically the same thing.